# Conditional probability p(C|A+B)

Tags: probability, self-learning, bayesian

I'm trying to express conditional probability of $p(C|A + B)$ (probability of $C$, given $A$ or $B$) using $p(C|A)$, $p(C|B)$, and $p(C|AB)$.

Using Venn's diagram I came up with:
$$p(C|A + B) = p(C|A) + p(C|B) - p(C|AB).$$

Is this correct? How can I prove this more formally?

Comment: Obviously wrong, try $A=\{a,c\}$, $B=\{a,b\}$ and $C=\{c\}$ for the uniform distribution on $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$. The identity you might have checked using Venn diagrams could be $$P(C,A+B)=P(C,A)+P(C,B)-P(C,AB)$$

Comment: @Did So, just to clarify, in case of what you are suggesting $p(C|A+B) = 1/3$, while $p(C|A) = 1/2$, $p(C|B)=0$, and $p(C|AB)=0$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect. I think you are confusing the identity:

$$P(A+B | C) = P(A|C)+P(B|C)-P(AB|C)$$

It is this result which you would have shown from venn diagrams. To see that this does not hold just let A,B,C be all independent and a contradiction will immediately arise unless they are all of probability 0.

Comment: If $A,B,C$ are all independent, wouldn't $p(C|A) = p(C|B) = p(C|AB) = p(C)$ thus giving us $p(C|A+B) = p(C)+p(C) - p(C) = p(C)$, which seems correct?

Comment: whoops yes you are right. Sorry about that. I see there is a counterexample above.