# Probability of a proposition conditional on a disjunction

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am reading through E.T. Jaynes' *Probability Theory: The Logic of Science*, and I am stuck on one of the exercises in Chapter 2. The exercise is

> Is it possible to find a general formula for $p(C|A + B)$, analogous to (2.66), from the product and sum rules? If so, derive it; if not, explain why this cannot be done.

where (2.66) is $p(A + B|C) = p(A|C) + p(B|C) − p(AB|C)$.

My intuition is that $p(C|A + B) = p(C|A) + p(C|B) - p(C|AB)$. But I can't see how to prove or disprove this from the product and sum rules. I don't see how to expand the expression $p(C|A + B)$, since there is only a single proposition on the left side of the conditional symbol. And I don't know of any identities that can be used for the expression on the right side of the conditional symbol.

For context, Jaynes gives the product and sum rules as:

**Product Rule:** $P(AB|C) = P(A|C)P(B|AC) = P(B|C)P(A|BC)$

**Sum Rule:** $P(A|C) + P(\neg{A}|C) = 1$

I have seen this previous posting which seems to be about the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293025/conditional-probability-pcab). But it doesn't look like there was any resolution.

This is my first post, so any meta comments on my question are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "analogous to (2.66)", I think Jaynes intends a formula that expresses $p(C∣A+B)$ in terms of conditional probabilities involving $A,B,C$ *only* -- which (due to the form of the sum and product rules) is evidently impossible without special assumptions about the propositions $A,B,C$. (The very next exercise in the book concerns such a special case.)

In your question you say ...

> My intuition is that $p(C|A+B)=p(C|A)+p(C|B)−p(C|AB)$.

... and in a comment ...

> But I’m not sure how to use [[the linked counterexample]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293025/conditional-probability-pcab#comment4717372_2293025) to demonstrate that the intuition is invalid. My understanding is that $\Omega$ is a distribution over three propositions, each having 1/3 probability. My attempt to plug that into the intuitive formula seems wrong: $P(C|A+B)=P(c|a,c)+P(c|a,b)−P(c|a,c,a,b).$

Your commas appear to stand for logical OR (otherwise denoted by $+$), so there's some confusion about the meaning of $AB$ (the [logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Definition) of propositions $A$ and $B$).

**NB**: The counterexample at your link applies when your equation is (mis-)interpreted in terms of standard probability-as-measure, whereas the context here is Jaynes' propositional theory of probability. (In this theory, there is no such object as an *unconditional* probability; in particular, the notation $P(A\mid B)$ does *not mean* $P(AB)/P(B)$ as it would in the standard theory.) However, it's easy to reformulate it as a counterexample in the present context, as follows:

Suppose $P(a\mid X)=P(b\mid X)=P(c\mid X)=1/3$, where proposition $X$ implies that the three propositions $a,b,c$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive (i.e., exactly one of the three is true and the other two are false). Now consider the propositions $A=a+c,\ B=a+b,\ C=c$. We have $(A+B)X=(a+b+c)X$, and $ABX=(a+c)(a+b)X=(aa+ab+ca+cb)X=aX$ because $X$ implies that $ab,ca$, and $cb$ are false. We then find the following: 
$$\begin{align}
P(C\mid AX+BX)&=P(c\mid (A+B)X)\\
&=P(c\mid (a+b+c)X)\\
&=P(c\mid X)\\
&=1/3 \\ \\
P(C\mid AX)&=P(c\mid (a+c)X)\\
&={P(c(a+c)\mid X)\over P(a+c)\mid X)}\\
&={P(c\mid X)\over P(a+c\mid X)}\\
&={1/3\over 2/3}\\
&=1/2\\ \\
P(C\mid BX)&=P(c\mid (a+b)X)\\
&=0\\ \\
P(C\mid ABX)&=P(c\mid aX)\\
&=0\\
\end{align}$$
Now if your intuitive formula were correct, then 
$$\underbrace{P(C\mid AX+BX)}_{1/3}=\underbrace{P(C\mid AX)}_{1/2}+\underbrace{P(C\mid BX)}_{0}-\underbrace{P(C\mid ABX)}_{0}$$ 
hence the formula is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your cited post, there is already a comment answering your question that the intuition is wrong. However you can always expand it, if you like:

$$ \begin{align} P(C|A \cup B) 
&= \frac {P(C \cap (A \cup B))} {P(A \cup B)} \\
&= \frac {P((C \cap A) \cup (C \cap B))} {P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)} \\
&= \frac {P(C \cap A) + P(C \cap B) - P(C \cap A \cap B)} {P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)}
\end{align}$$

Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: By "analogous to (2.66)", I think Jaynes intends a formula that expresses $p(C\mid A+B)$ in terms of *conditional* probabilities involving $A,B,C$ *only* -- which I suspect is impossible unless some special assumptions are made about $A,B,C$. (For example, in this answer the unconditional probabilities can be written as conditional on a sample space, say $S$, but then that introduces an additional symbol $S$ for the sample space.

Comment: @BGM Ah, I see the comment giving a counter example. But I’m not sure how to use it to demonstrate that the intuition is invalid. My understanding is that $\Omega$ is a distribution over three propositions, each having 1/3 probability. My attempt to plug that into the intuitive formula seems wrong: $P(C|A+B) = P(c|a, c) +P(c|a, b) - P(c|a, c, a, b)$